# CoreService GetList() behaving differently to GetListXml()

Tags: core-service

I am trying to use GetList to return all the users in a group, as below:

```
client.GetList(id, new GroupMembersFilterData())
```

However, I get the exception

> {"Unexpected list type: Tridion.ContentManager.Data.Security.GroupMembersFilterData."}

When I use

```
client.GetListXml(id, new GroupMembersFilterData())
```

It works! Can anyone explain?

Normally I would probably use Xml anyway, but as I was doing a quick POC I thought I would make it easier and use objects.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The Content Manager Core Service API Reference Guide shows `ICoreService2011.GetList` takes two parameters:

1. TCM URI (or WebDAV URL) as a `string`
2. a `Tridion.ContentManager.Data.SubjectRelatedListFilterData` filter

However, there's a remark that "Currently only **OrganizationalItemAncestorsFilterData** filter is supported."

The `SubjectRelatedListFilterData` (abstract) class's inheritance includes:

- BluePrintChainFilterData
- CategoryRelatedFilterData
- ClassifiedItemsFilterData
- DeletedReferencesFilterData
- ItemsFilterData
- KeywordRelatedFilterData
- **OrganizationalItemAncestorsFilterData**
- OrganizationalItemsFilterData
- PathToCategoryFilterData
- RepositoryRelatedFilterData
- TaxonomiesFilterData
- VersionsFilterData
- GroupMembersFilterData
- WhereUsedFilterData

Long list short, use GetListXml() for any filter that isn't an `OrganizationalItemAncestorsFilterData` for SDL Tridion 2011.

**Update**: in at least SDL Tridion 2013, you should be able to get back objects on most filters.

`ICoreService2012.GetList`'s updated remark notes that just `TaxonomiesOwlFilterData` is not supported.