# how to get list of pages in a structure group using core service in 2013

Tags: core-service

While searching the solution I found [How would I get all pages using core service?](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/2516/how-would-i-get-all-pages-using-core-service) where it get list of SG while providing publication URI as RepositoryItemsFilterData . I am trying to use it to get the list of pages in  an SG. However when I give SG TCM ID as RepositoryItemsFilterData core service gives me error 'Unexpected item type: StructureGroup.' I am writing code something like below. Can someone help to me on how to get pages when you have SG TCMID.

```
    public List<string> PagesToRemove(string structureGroupTCMID)
               {

                        var itemTypes = new List<ItemType>();
                        itemTypes.Add(ItemType.Page);    
                        var filter = new RepositoryItemsFilterData();
                        filter.Recursive=true;                
                        filter.ItemTypes = itemTypes.ToArray();    
                        var listXml =_CoreServiceClient.GetList(structureGroupTCMID, filter);
                        List<string> lstPageTCMID = new List<string>();
                       //code to map listXml to lstPageTCMID
                        return lstPageTCMID;
                    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of using RepositoryItemsFilterData, you should use OrganizationalItemItemsFilterData.

You can use following code to filter the pages from a structured group:

```
       _CoreServiceClient.GetListXml(structureGroupTCMID, new OrganizationalItemItemsFilterData
        {
            ItemTypes = new[] { ItemType.Page },
            Recursive = true,
            BaseColumns = ListBaseColumns.Default
        });
```