# how to get bundle information of a page using core service

Tags: core-service, workflow, bundles

I am reading tridion Page of type `PageData` via core service. The page is attached to a bundle but the bundle is not in a workflow. Is it possible to get the attached bundle information from the PageData Object? I have gone through the PageData class in `Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.PageData` and it is having following properties

```
public class PageData : VersionedItemData
    {
        public LinkToApprovalStatusData ApprovalStatus { get; set; }

        public ComponentPresentationData[] ComponentPresentations { get; set; }

        public string FileName { get; set; }

        public bool? IsPageTemplateInherited { get; set; }

        public LinkToPageTemplateData PageTemplate { get; set; }

        public RegionDictionary Regions { get; set; }

        public LinkToSchemaData RegionSchema { get; set; }

        public WorkflowInfo WorkflowInfo { get; set; }
     }
```

`WorkflowInfo` in Null as Bundle in not in Workflow and other properties doesn't contains any information about the bundle.

Can someone help me here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use ContainingBundlesFilterData and use following code to get bundles to which particular item is part of:

```
ContainingBundlesFilterData filter = new ContainingBundlesFilterData();

var bundles = _CoreServiceClient.GetList(<ItemId>, filter);
```

Comment: Is it possible to club ContainingBundlesFilterData with OrganizationalItemItemsFilterData 
http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/12872/how-to-get-list-of-pages-in-a-structure-group-using-core-service-in-2013 ?

Comment: I am not aware of any such direct API using which you can combine these two filters.

Comment: channel = your core service client, right?

Comment: Yes, updated the answer to reflect it.